# Count Favorite ms-access

Tags: ms-access, count, favorite

I have 3 existing tables: Instructor, Feedback, Class

In Feedback table, 2 columns

```
Class_ID
Likes
```

(Class_ID link with the attendance, as each member attend 1 class eg. class 1,2,3,etc. and Likes is for the number of people like the class).

In Instructor table, column relevant:

```
Instructor_ID
```

In Class table, column relevant:

```
Class_ID
Instructor_ID
```

I need a query to report a favorite instructor i.e instructor_ID with max(likes).

```
Select
Class_ID.Class,
Instructor_ID.Instructor,
Likes.Feedback
WHERE Max(Likes.Feedback)
```

Suggestions/Corrections are welcomed.Thank you

**EDIT**

```
Select
Exercise_class_attendance.Class_ID,
Exercise_Instructor.Instructor_ID,
Feedback_FaceBook.Likes,
Max(Likes) FROM Feedback_Facebook AS Highest_Number_Like
GROUP BY Instructor_ID
```

This is the query I am working on and it asked me to enter parameter value of every element in the code. Spelling checked.

Comment: How about you look at some of the ideas you have gathered in your previous posts rather than sticking in random code that is not even generated by the query design window, a very useful tool?

Comment: its not the same question,as when I read your comment on the other thread I realize it is not possible so I move on with other questions. I am new with access, so I need helps. You have been the most helpful so far. Thank you

Comment: It is not that it is not possible, it is not recommended to update a table with a column that changes and you do not have to do it. You can use a query that will show you the information you require. Use the query design window to build such a query and then post the sql here if it is not what you want. Just pasting random sql is not a good idea.

Comment: The question has been updated with the query I was working on. It's not that I write a random sql,just want to post a simple looking question :'(

Answer (score 1):

If you use the query design window, it will show you where the problem(s) are. You cannot have a field (column) that is not part of GROUP BY or summed/counted etc:

```
Select
Exercise_class_attendance.Class_ID,
Exercise_Instructor.Instructor_ID,
Feedback_FaceBook.Likes,
Max(Likes) AS Highest_Number_Like
FROM Feedback_Facebook, Exercise_class_attendance, Exercise_Instructor
GROUP BY Exercise_Instructor.Instructor_ID, Exercise_class_attendance.Class_ID,
   Feedback_FaceBook.Likes
```

This is **not** a good query, it is only some notes.

You will make like a lot easier for yourself if you read up on aliases.

Comment: it still ask me to enter parameter value of Exercise_class_attendance.Class_ID,
Exercise_Instructor.Instructor_ID,
Feedback_FaceBook.Likes,

Comment: I have added what I think to be the additional table names, but it still won't be a good query because there are no joins. You really need to start using the query design window. That way, you can post something like valid sql which won't leave people guessing what comes from what.

Comment: You need to add the tables to the query design window and drag the fields that the tables are related on from one to the other to create valid joins, then choose sigma : Σ from the menu bar to create an aggregate query. Access will automatically add GROUP BY to each field (column). You can then set sum or count or whatever for the field(s) you want to aggregate.

Comment: @HansUp you have a [roblem with my spelling, hm? :)